# Add a mime type to JBoss EAP

Tags: jboss, mime-types, jnlp

I want to know if there is a way to add a new mime type in a JBoss' configuration (standalone.xml) file and not in a .war because I serve a jnlp archive in the "welcome content" folder but when I try to download the archive the browser (Chrome) shows the xml.

Thanks

Comment: You can move all your "welcome content" to another .war file and configure mime type. https://developer.jboss.org/message/761040

Comment: First I had a .war who have the jnlp. But I made updates on that .war everyday (the update last 8 minutes) so I wanted to use the welcome-content where the update last at least 1 minute

Comment: May be this separate .war will be faster to redeploy. Also you can test exploded deploying. And finally you can place your files in any place but use servlet to give that files with needed mime type.

Comment: I didn't know anything about exploded deploying. I read a bit about that but there is something that I don't understand: I have to create a folder in my deployments folder called as the same way to my .war?

Comment: Yes. It was create a new folder called as I want to know to be the .war called and then I add a file callerd [folder.war.dodeploy]

Comment: i know this question is a bit old, but is there a solution to this, i have that problem.

Comment: @jaramator I remember that I used a exploded war to serve my static content.